# How to make a number format?

Tags: java, android

I want to format number which I receive from the local database

**Example:**

10000 to 10.000 or 1000000 to 100.000

**My code:**

```
holder.mTextViewHarga.setText("Rp. " + mProdukList.get(position).gethargaProduk());
```

i have to try this code before but still error:

```
Locale localeID = new Locale("in", "ID");
NumberFormat formatRupiah = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(localeID);

holder.mTextViewHarga.setText("Rp. " +formatRupiah.format((double) mProdukList.get(position).gethargaProduk()));
```

Comment: Can you post the details of the error you are getting including the error message and the stack trace?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a number formatter as shown in the example below:

```
NumberFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
double myNumber = 1234.5632;
String formattedNumber = myFormatter.format(myNumber);
```

and formattedNumber will be equal to "1234.563"

Answer (score 3):

Use DecimalFormat()

```
DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat( "#,###,###,##0.00" );
double d = 100.2397;
double d1 = new Double(df2.format(d)).doubleValue();
```

Output - d1 will be 100.24

Answer (score 2):

The DecimalFormat class: It is a Java class that allows us to display the numbers with a desired format, it can be a limit the decimals, use the period, comma, etc. example

```
//required import
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("####.####");
//It prints four decimals, like this: 7,1234
System.out.println (formatter.format (7.12342383));
```

If we use zeros instead of #, the non-existent digits will be filled with zeros, an example:

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0000.0000");
//It prints: 0001,8200
System.out.println (formatter.format (1.82));
```

We can also use the percent sign (%) in the mask and so the number will be automatically multiplied by 100 at the time of printing.

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###.##%");
//It prints: 68,44%
System.out.println (formatter.format(0.6844));
```

Answer (score 1):

As from [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html), the answer would be

```
Locale localeID = new Locale("in", "ID");
String pattern = "###,###.###";
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(localeID);
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;
df.applyPattern(pattern);
String output = df.format(value);
```